# Angularjs select multiple options dont work

Tags: angularjs, json, controller

I'm filling a select multiple with data coming from a Web API, but I want to display the selected values ​​in another query and it does not work

Model

```
$scope.clickevent = function (id, name) {
    $scope.id = id

    $scope.fleetFeatures = fleetFeatures.list;

    $http.get(myUrl + "FleetFeatures/Selected?id_fleet=" + $scope.id).then(function (data) {
        $scope.selectedFeatures = data.data;
    });
}
```

View

```
       <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select class="" id="features" ng-model="selectedFeatures" ng-options="item.FleetFeatureId as item.FleetFeatureName for item in fleetFeatures" multiple material-select watch>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>{{translation.fleet5}}</option>
                </select>
        </div>
```

fleetFeatures

```
[{"$id":"1","Fleet_FleetFeatures":[],"FleetFeatureId":1,"FleetFeatureName":"Advanced Geocoding Features","FleetFeatureCode":1,"FleetFeatureData":null},{"$id":"2","Fleet_FleetFeatures":[],"FleetFeatureId":2,"FleetFeatureName":"feature 2","FleetFeatureCode":2,"FleetFeatureData":null},{"$id":"3","Fleet_FleetFeatures":[],"FleetFeatureId":3,"FleetFeatureName":"feature 3","FleetFeatureCode":672,"FleetFeatureData":null}]
```

selectedFeatures

```
[{"$id":"1","FleetFeatureId":3},{"$id":"2","FleetFeatureId":1}]
```

I'm missing something in the code, because the select me loads it but it does not show me anything selected

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As you are already grabing `FleetFeatureId` instead of whole item by doing  `item.FleetFeatureId as item.FleetFeatureName`. You should be specifying `selectedFeatures` should be like below

```
[3, 1]
```

Comment: =) ... you have been to quick.